# Current and voltage, thermal flashers (bimetallic blinkers)

Tags: current, thermal, metal

I am looking for *voltage vs time* and *current vs time* plots at the load side for an automotive old time turn signal blinker in series with a switch and a standard 21 W incandescent light bulb. I was not able to find such graphs on the Internet. Does anyone have them?

Comment: That's a perfect occasion to do the measurements and post them online :)

Answer (score 5):

SAE J1690, I believe, covers the basic requirements. Rate should be 60-120 flashes per minute tested at nominal 12.8/24°C and four extreme voltage/temperature combinations from 11 to 15V and -17°C to 50°C.

There is probably a duty cycle requirement of 35% to 75% and maybe other requirements
such as time to first flash (maybe 1.5 seconds), but I don't have access to the standard. You can infer an lower limit on the strictness of the requirements by the specifications of real products, which may not guarantee anything better than the minimum requirements (but may).

Eletromechanical flashers are load-dependent. They would typically drop < 1V when 'on', perhaps 500 or 800mV. That voltage drop is mostly due to the power that heats the bimetallic strip rather than the contacts. The load dependency (and the sound they make) are inherent characteristics that are actually features (a change in flash rate would indicate a dead tail light incandescent bulb, and the sound would remind the driver to turn the signal off).

So anyway, the curve during operation is some voltage square wave (more or less, with soft edge at turn-on due to the current spike) at the lamp of maybe 10 to 14.5V- a bit less than the supply voltage, of some duty cycle as mentioned above, and at some rate, again as mentioned above. The current curve will be similar but with a substantial current spike each cycle as the bulb turns on (since tungsten has a positive temperature coefficient). The voltage curve at the flasher will probably show some spikes at turn-off due to wiring harness inductance.

TL;DR: If you don't look too carefully, at the lamp, it's just a square-ish wave of reasonable duty cycle and almost the supply voltage.

Comment: -17C! Thats a high low temperature test limit.

Comment: @MrGerber Yes, I wonder if that was a compromise to the limitations of the bimetal thermal technology of the day. Functional but perhaps sluggish at a more reasonable -40°C was deemed acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

The voltage vs time chart will be a squarewave with voltage switching from 0 to V<sub>bat</sub>. Duty cycle may be load dependent. The good ones will have frequency dependent on the load so that they blink at a faster rate in the event of a single bulb failure (so that the driver can be aware of a fault).

The current curve will be pretty much that of an incandescent lamp (or pair). It will start off high due to cold filament resistance being low and the current will fall as the filament heats up. Modelling that will  get you good results but you'll have to figure out how much the filament cools during the off periods.

I doubt anyone has published the data you're looking for as it's generally not needed.

Comment: The blink rate for automotive use is probably limited to a fixed range for type approval (0.1 Hz would not be useful in traffic, nor is 100 Hz). Someone should have an old datasheet.